# Want to set dynamic folder name in flowFactoryProvider config to pass it to upload.php file to save the uploaded file in it

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ng-flow

I am using this plugin [ng-flow](http://webmail.techphant.com/appsuite/ng-flow) for uploading .zip file and it is working properly. I need to pass dynamic values (user_id, job_id) in it for creating dynamic folders where the files get saved but this plugin uses config method to get initialize and I am not getting the way to pass dynamic value in config method

below are the codes which I have used

view part - [index.html](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/blob/master/samples/basic/index.html)

server part - [upload.php](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/blob/master/samples/basic/upload.php)

controller part - [app.js](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/blob/master/samples/basic/app.js) , here you will find a config function where I want to pass dynamic values to server part. In Config method I have tried to define a provider to access dynamic values but I didn't find out the way. Is there any way to access values in config (values which i want to access is in localstorageService plugin)

Hope I have explained you clearly.Any help or suggestion would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In you index.html file add and initialize value:

```
<div ng-controller="dataCtrl">
     <input ng-init="id=2374897289345" type="hidden"/>
</div>
```

Then open app.js and add controller with following code:

```
.controller('dataCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log('Hello');
    $scope.$on('flow::fileAdded', function (event, $flow, flowFile) {       
        $flow.opts.query = {id:$scope.id};
    });

}])
```

Now can access your file in post.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution how i can pass dynamic value dynamic values to server part.

first set flow init in your view portion

```
  <div flow-init = "{
                                target: '../../dummy.php',
                                permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
                                maxChunkRetries: 1,
                                chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
                                simultaneousUploads: 4,
                                headers: config
                  };">
```

Then set dynamic to this config variable of header in your controller

```
$scope.config = {
        id: localStorageService.get('userkey').id, 
        token: localStorageService.get('userkey').token
  };
```

(localStorageService contain my login details)

now you can access this id and token from server side by using $_SERVER

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ID'];
$_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN'];
```